# How to call API to gather json information from openweathermap.org in android studio

Tags: android, xml, api, android-studio, openweathermap

I am new to android development and I am building a weather app in android studio using java.
I want to use the API from openweathermap.org to get information about the weather using latitude and longitude points. I generated an API key but when I click on the URL of open weather map in my code, it displays error 401 and no JSON information is displayed and when I run the application in the emulator, it displays a toast message of "Request Failed" which I coded in the onfailure method.I am stuck on this problem for 3 days . I am attaching the code below.

```
  package com.londonappbrewery.climapm;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;



import org.json.JSONObject;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;


public class WeatherController extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Constants:
    final int REQUEST_CODE =123;
    final String WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
    final String APP_ID = "8256c76143428856df5bc4985ff9e5ef";
    // Time between location updates (5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds)
    final long MIN_TIME = 5000;
    // Distance between location updates (1000m or 1km)
    final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;

    // TODO: Set LOCATION_PROVIDER here:
    String LOCATION_PROVIDER = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;


    // Member Variables:
    TextView mCityLabel;
    ImageView mWeatherImage;
    TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    LocationListener mLocationListener;


    // TODO: Declare a LocationManager and a LocationListener here:



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weather_controller_layout);

        // Linking the elements in the layout to Java code
        mCityLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationTV);
        mWeatherImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weatherSymbolIV);
        mTemperatureLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempTV);
        ImageButton changeCityButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changeCityButton);


        // TODO: Add an OnClickListener to the changeCityButton here:

    }


    // TODO: Add onResume() here:
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWeatherForCurrentLocation();
    }


    // TODO: Add getWeatherForNewCity(String city) here:


    // TODO: Add getWeatherForCurrentLocation() here:
    private void getWeatherForCurrentLocation() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.d("Clima","onLocationChanges() callback recieved");
                String latitude= String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                String longitude= String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                Log.d("Clima","latitude is"+latitude);
                Log.d("Clima","longitude is"+longitude);
                RequestParams params= new RequestParams();
                params.put("lat",latitude);
                params.put("lon",longitude);
                params.put("appid",APP_ID);
                letsDoSomeNetworking(params);




            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Log.d("Clima","onProviderDisabled(), callback recieved");

            }
        };
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);

            return;
        }
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d("Clima","Permission granted!");
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Clima","Permission denied");
        }
    }
    // TODO: Add letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params) here:
    private void letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params){
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(WEATHER_URL, params,new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
                Log.d("Clima","Success ! JSON "+response.toString());
                WeatherDataModel weatherData = WeatherDataModel.fromJson(response);
                Toast.makeText(WeatherController.this,"Request succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateUI(weatherData);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode,Header[] headers, Throwable e,JSONObject response){
                Log.d("Clima","Fail ! "+e.toString());
                Log.d("Clima","Status Code"+ statusCode);
               Toast.makeText(WeatherController.this,"Request failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });
    }


    // TODO: Add updateUI() here:
  private void  updateUI(WeatherDataModel weather){
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(weather.getTemperature());
        mCityLabel.setText(weather.getCity());

        int ResourceID= getResources().getIdentifier(weather.getIconName(),"drawable",getPackageName());
        mWeatherImage.setImageResource(ResourceID);



    }



    // TODO: Add onPause() here:



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means wrong authantification, are you sure your API key is OK ? Check with Post man your request with all your parameters to confirm it.

I think the problem come from how you send your params

Answer (score 0):

Add your LOCATION_NAME and APP_ID as query or just add at the end of your url
like this:

```
WEATHER_URL + "?q=newyork&appid=APP_ID"
```

[read document of this API here](https://openweathermap.org/current)

By city name
Description:
You can call by city name or city name, state code and country code. API responds with a list of weather parameters that match a search request.
API call:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={your api key}

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name},{state code}&appid={your api key}

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name},{state code},{country code}&appid={your api key}
```

simply you can do this:

```
// TODO: Add letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params) here:
private void letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get((WEATHER_URL + "?q=newyork&appid=APP_ID"), params,new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
            Log.d("Clima","Success ! JSON "+response.toString());
            WeatherDataModel weatherData = WeatherDataModel.fromJson(response);
            Toast.makeText(WeatherController.this,"Request succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            updateUI(weatherData);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode,Header[] headers, Throwable e,JSONObject response){
            Log.d("Clima","Fail ! "+e.toString());
            Log.d("Clima","Status Code"+ statusCode);
           Toast.makeText(WeatherController.this,"Request failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the APP_ID you've got in the query string parameter of the URL along with the City you would like to search for.

Here is the sample request with your AppID: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=8256c76143428856df5bc4985ff9e5ef&q=london